# Filtering a paged list in Blazor

Tags: .net-core, blazor-server-side

I have a Blazor app where I have a list of objects in a List.  I set up a Pager Component (shown below) and it works great.  Then I set up search box functionality on a set of fields from the list.  All of this works great if the Pager is on the first page.  Any other pages and the searches show unpredictable results.  Sometimes not even filtering correctly for items on that page.  Any advice would be helpful.  Thanks.

**Pager.razor**

```
@typeparam TItem

<div class="row d-flex col-9">
<div class="justify-content-center">
    @if (PageCount > 1 && List.Count > PageSize)
    {
        <ul class="pagination justify-content-center">
            <li><button @onclick="@(() => ChangePage(1))" class="btn">&laquo;</button></li>

                @for (var i = StartIndex; i <= FinishIndex; i++)
                {
                    var currentIndex = i;
                    @if (i == CurrentPage)
                    {
                        <li class="page-item active"><span class="btn">@i</span></li>
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        <li class="page-item"><button class="btn page-link" @onclick="@(() => ChangePage(currentIndex))">@i</button></li>
                    }
                }

            <li><button @onclick="@(() => ChangePage(PageCount))" class="btn">&raquo;</button></li>
        </ul>
    }   
</div>
<select class="custom-select offset-1 col-1 ml-auto" bind="@PageSize" @onchange="@(e => ChangePageSize(e))">
    <option value="10">10</option>
    <option value="25">25</option>
    <option value="50">50</option>
</select>
</div>

@code {
    [Parameter]
    public List<TItem> List { get; set; }

    public List<TItem> Display { get; set; }

    [Parameter]
    public Action<List<TItem>> DisplayChanged { get; set; }

    [Parameter]
    public Action<bool> Rendered { get; set; }

    private int PageSize { get; set; } = 10;
    private int CurrentPage { get; set; } = 1;
    private int StartIndex { get; set; }
    private int FinishIndex { get; set; }
    private int PageCount { get; set; }

    protected override void OnAfterRender(bool firstRender)
    {
        base.OnAfterRender(firstRender);
        Rendered?.Invoke(true);
    }

    private void ChangePageSize(ChangeEventArgs e)
    {
        PageSize = int.Parse(e.Value.ToString());
        ChangePage(1);
    }

    private void ChangeDisplay()
    {
        DisplayChanged?.Invoke(
            List
                .Skip((CurrentPage - 1) * PageSize)
                .Take(PageSize)
                .ToList()
        );
    }

    protected override void OnParametersSet()
    {
        ResetIndex();

        ChangeDisplay();
        base.OnParametersSet();
    }

    protected void ChangePage(int page)
    {
        CurrentPage = page;
        ResetIndex();
        ChangeDisplay();
    }

    private void ResetIndex()
    {
        PageCount = List.Count / PageSize;

        if (List.Count % PageSize > 0)
        {
            PageCount++;
        }

        StartIndex = Math.Max(CurrentPage - 5, 1);
        FinishIndex = Math.Min(CurrentPage + 5, PageCount);
    }
}
```

**Pager Use**
`<Pager List="@FilteredUsers" DisplayChanged="@DisplayChanged" Rendered="@PagerRendered" />`

**Search Function**

```
<input class="form-control" type="text" @bind-value="@SearchTerm" @bind-value:event="oninput" />
<select class="form-control" @bind-value="@Property" @bind-value:event="onchange">
    <option value="FirstName">First Name</option>
    <option value="LastName">Last Name</option>
    <option value="Role">Role</option>
    <option value="Property">Property</option>
</select>

private string searchTerm;

private string SearchTerm
{
    get => searchTerm;
    set
    {
        searchTerm = value;
        Filter();
    }
}
```

**Filter**

```
private void Filter()
{
    switch (Property)
    {
        case "FirstName":
            FilteredUsers = Users.Where(u => u.FirstName.ToLower().Contains(SearchTerm.ToLower())).ToList();
            break;
        case "LastName":
            FilteredUsers = Users.Where(u => u.LastName.ToLower().Contains(SearchTerm.ToLower())).ToList();
            break;
        case "Role":
            FilteredUsers = Users.Where(u => u.Role.ToString().ToLower().Contains(SearchTerm.ToLower())).ToList();
            break;
        case "Property":
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(SearchTerm))
            {
                FilteredUsers = Users;
            }
            else
            {
                FilteredUsers = Users.Where(u => TicketingRosters.Any(t => t.Property.PropertyName.ToLower().Contains(SearchTerm.ToLower()) && u.UserId == t.SellerId)).ToList();
            }
            break;
    }
    StateHasChanged();
}
```

**Edit**

Here are the other functions and Properties that you may be looking for:

```
private List<UserDto> Users { get; set; }
private List<UserDto> FilteredUsers { get; set; }
private List<UserDto> Display { get; set; }

private bool IsPagerRendered { get; set; }
private void DisplayChanged(List<UserDto> display)
{
    Display = display;
}

private void PagerRendered(bool rendered)
{
    IsPagerRendered = rendered;
    StateHasChanged();
}
```

**Edit 2**
`private List<TicketingRoster> TicketingRosters { get; set; } = new List<TicketingRoster>();`

**UserDto**

```
#nullable enable
using System;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

namespace TicketingSolutions.Models.DTOs
{
    public class UserDto
    {
        public long UserId { get; set; }
        [Required(AllowEmptyStrings = false, ErrorMessage = "First name cannot be empty.")]
        [StringLength(75, ErrorMessage = "First Name too long.  (75 characters)")]
        public string? FirstName { get; set; }
        [Required(AllowEmptyStrings = false, ErrorMessage = "Last Name cannot be empty.")]
        [StringLength(75, ErrorMessage = "Last Name too long. (75 characters)")]
        public string? LastName { get; set; }
        [StringLength(75, ErrorMessage = "Middle Name too long. (75 characters)")]
        public string? MiddleName { get; set; }
        [StringLength(150, ErrorMessage = "Title too long. (150 characters)")]
        public string? Title { get; set; }
        [DataType(DataType.EmailAddress)]
        [StringLength(150, ErrorMessage = "Email Address too long. (150 characters)")]
        public string? EmailAddress { get; set; }
        [RegularExpression(@"((\(\d{3}\) ?)|(\d{3}-))?\d{3}-\d{4}", ErrorMessage = "Not a valid phone number format: (xxx) xxx-xxxx")]
        [StringLength(50, ErrorMessage = "Phone Number too long. (50 characters)")]
        public string? OfficePhone { get; set; }
        [RegularExpression(@"((\(\d{3}\) ?)|(\d{3}-))?\d{3}-\d{4}", ErrorMessage = "Not a valid phone number format: (xxx) xxx-xxxx")]
        [StringLength(50, ErrorMessage = "Phone Number too long. (50 characters)")]
        public string? OtherPhone { get; set; }
        public Guid? AdUserId { get; set; }
        public bool IsActive { get; set; }
        public int? RegionId { get; set; }
        public Region? Region { get; set; }
        public DateTime CreatedOn { get; set; }
        public long CreatedBy { get; set; }
        public DateTime ModifiedOn { get; set; }
        public long ModifiedBy { get; set; }

        public Roles Role { get; set; }

        public int? RoleId { get; set; }
        public CommissionRole? CommissionRole { get; set; }
    }
}
```

**TicketingRoster**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace TicketingSolutions.Models
{
    [Table("TicketingRosters")]
    public class TicketingRoster : IValidatableObject
    {
        [Key]
        public long TicketingRosterId { get; set; }
        public int PropertyId { get; set; }
        public Property Property { get; set; }
        public long SellerId { get; set; }
        public User Seller { get; set; }
        public bool IsActive { get; set; }
        public DateTime ValidFrom { get; set; }
        public DateTime? ValidTo { get; set; }
        public DateTime CreatedOn { get; set; }
        public long CreatedBy { get; set; }
        public DateTime ModifiedOn { get; set; }
        public long ModifiedBy { get; set; }

        public IEnumerable<ValidationResult> Validate(ValidationContext validationContext)
        {
            if (ValidTo <= ValidFrom)
            {
                yield return new ValidationResult("ValidTo cannot be set to a date before or equal to ValidFrom", new[] { nameof(ValidTo) });
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a bit hard to follow as there are some external methods that you haven't shown in this example (edit maybe for clarity?) but it appears that you are using something outside your **Pager.razor** to dictate how your paging works. The giveaway is the `DisplayChanged` event callback. I can suggest that you tackle this by breaking up the concerns, and you can get everything working. (I was able to get it running fairly quickly working from what you have)

First off, let's set the Pager up so all it does is handle paging the information, and it contains all of it's own logic to do so in a self contained, reusable component. give it a list of `TItem` and a `RenderFragment<TItem>` and it knows what to do.

```cs
@typeparam TItem

<div class="row d-flex col-9">
    <div class="justify-content-center">

        @if (List != null)
        {
            @foreach (var item in DisplayList)
            {
                @ChildContent(item)
            }
        }

        @if (PageCount > 1 && List.Count > PageSize)
        {

            ...Nothing here was changed, eliminated for brevity...


        }
    </div>
    <select class="custom-select offset-1 col-1 ml-auto" bind="@PageSize" @onchange="@(e => ChangePageSize(e))">
        <option value="10">10</option>
        <option value="25">25</option>
        <option value="50">50</option>
    </select>
</div>

@code {
    [Parameter]
    public List<TItem> List { get; set; }

    public List<TItem> DisplayList { get; set; } = new List<TItem>();

    [Parameter]
    public RenderFragment<TItem> ChildContent { get; set; }

    //[Parameter]
    //public Action<List<TItem>> DisplayChanged { get; set; }

    //[Parameter]
    //public Action<bool> Rendered { get; set; }

    private int PageSize { get; set; } = 10;
    private int CurrentPage { get; set; } = 1;
    private int StartIndex { get; set; }
    private int FinishIndex { get; set; }
    private int PageCount { get; set; }

    //protected override void OnAfterRender(bool firstRender)
    //{
    //  base.OnAfterRender(firstRender);
    //  Rendered?.Invoke(true);
    //}

    private void ChangePageSize(ChangeEventArgs e)
    {
        PageSize = int.Parse(e.Value.ToString());
        ChangePage(1);
    }

    private void ChangeDisplay()
    {
        DisplayList = List
                .Skip((CurrentPage -1) * PageSize)
                .Take(PageSize)
                .ToList();
    }

    protected override void OnParametersSet()
    {
        // Edited
        ChangePage(1);
    }

    protected void ChangePage(int page)
    {
        CurrentPage = page;
        ResetIndex();
        ChangeDisplay();
    }

    private void ResetIndex()
    {
        PageCount = List.Count / PageSize;

        if (List.Count % PageSize > 0)
        {
            PageCount++;
        }

        StartIndex = Math.Max(CurrentPage - 5, 1);
        FinishIndex = Math.Min(CurrentPage + 5, PageCount);
    }
}
```

You'll see that a few things in the @code block are commented out. You won't need these to get this working. We'll handle the values in the initial list in a minute in the Parent component. You'll see a `RenderFragment<TItem>` parameter, and a new property for `DisplayList` that is NOT a parameter. You'll also notice in the markup, we have a `@foreach` block rendering an instance of our `RenderFragment` for each item in the `DisplayList` property. If you follow the logic from the `OnParametersSet` method and your handlers for clicking the page numbers and arrows, you'll see that we are creating and rendering a sub-list of our `List` parameter based on page count and page number, and that is all that is rendered. This component is now responsible for paging items from a list it's given, and it has no external dependencies to run other than a list to render, and instructions on how to render each item in the form of a `RenderFragment<TItem>`.

Next, in the **Parent** component, we set up the call to the pager like so:

```cs
<Pager TItem="User" List="FilteredUsers">
    <h6>@context.FirstName @context.LastName is in @context.Role </h6>
</Pager>
```

You can set this up however you'd like, I used `<h6>` tags for illustration, but follow the directions [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/templated-components?view=aspnetcore-3.1) if you need more depth, creating tables, lists, etc. This component now accepts the child content between the `<Pager>` tags and renders 1 each for every item in it's own paged list.

So far, we've decoupled the pager's logic from the rest of the page, so now it's a rendering tool only and the paging logic is internal. Now we can focus on the filtering and forget about the paging.

**Search filtering:**
 First off, I set an initial value for the search "Property" and set a backing field like so:

```cs
private string property = "FirstName";

private string Property
{
    get => property;
    set
    {
        property = value;
        Filter();
    }
}
```

This now aligns with the drop down starting value, since the `<select>` only updated this on change, and also updates search results when you change the dropdown.

I left your `SearchTerm` property like you had it.

Now in the Filter method:

```cs
private void Filter()
{
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(SearchTerm))
    {
        FilteredUsers = Users;
    }
    else
    {
        switch (Property)
        {
            case "FirstName":
                FilteredUsers = Users.Where(u => u.FirstName.ToLower().Contains(SearchTerm.ToLower())).ToList();
                break;
            case "LastName":
                FilteredUsers = Users.Where(u => u.LastName.ToLower().Contains(SearchTerm.ToLower())).ToList();
                break;
            case "Role":
                FilteredUsers = Users.Where(u => u.Role.ToString().ToLower().Contains(SearchTerm.ToLower())).ToList();
                break;
            case "Property":
                FilteredUsers = Users.Where(u => u.Role.ToString().ToLower().Contains(SearchTerm.ToLower())).ToList();
                //FilteredUsers = Users.Where(u => TicketingRosters.Any(t => t.Property.PropertyName.ToLower().Contains(SearchTerm.ToLower()) && u.UserId == t.SellerId)).ToList();
                break;
            default:
                FilteredUsers = Users;
                break;
        }
    }
    StateHasChanged();
}
```

This now checks for a search value first, and returns the full `Users` list if it's empty. If not, then you enter the switch. The cases all work as I have them, however you'll see that I commented out the `Where` logic you had originally. Honestly, TicketingRosters is not familiar to me and I can tell your logic is in a domain I know nothing about, so you'll have to reason about that last case on your own. BUT, if everything else works, you now have a focused approach to where to find your bug.

So now the Filter method sets up a filtered list, the Pager takes that entire list and handles paging on it's own, and you have nicely separated concerns, so if you have a problem you know where to look. Not paging correctly -> it's in the pager. Not filtering correctly -> it's in the filter logic.

**Edit**

After the OP added the `TicketingRoster` and `UserDto` class definitions, I made the mistake of thinking I had found the issue in the query. However, through some back and forth the OP cleared up that the `Pager` I outlined above was still not functioning quite right and the queries were, and after another look I cleared up the `OnParametersSet` method to call `ChnagePage(1)`, which will both reset the current page to 1 and reset the page count. A test on my side confirmed the OP's issue with my original response had been cleared up.

My first edit contained quite a bit about the query structure and theory, and I removed that section because a) it is no longer relevant to this discussion, and b) looking back, it may have come off as condescending, though that was never my intention at any point.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer.  If you tell me what you would like to see, I can edit the question.  Not sure which aspect you are fuzzy on.

Comment: Specifically if I could see where ```TicketingRosters``` lives, and assuming that is a collection, the type definition (class, struct, primitive) that it holds in the collection as well. Seeing those properties you are querying against and how that last case in the Filter method interacts will shed some more light on this. I also assume there was a ```DisplayChanged``` method in the parent component that you didn't outline, however I don't know if it's needed.

Comment: Edits made.  Thanks for the help, by the way. :)

Comment: Added an edit to the bottom of my post, take a look and let me know if it clarifies things.

Comment: So maybe I can clarify things a bit.  There are 4 'fields' that I want to search by.  The first three (FirstName, LastName and Role) are all available on the UserDto objects.  The last is the name of the property that is tied to the TicketingRoster which is a compound table that links the Users and the Properties.  Again, all four of these searches are successfully and working as expected if the Pager is on the First page.  Any other pages of the Pager and it does not work correctly.  Unexpected results.

Comment: Take a look at the OnParametersSet method of the ```Pager```, I edited it so now it resets to page 1 when the supplied list is updated, so you see the results. Hopefully this has it running as you expect.